# Easiest way to test casefolded equality for two pathlib.Paths?

Tags: python, case-insensitive, pathlib, case-folding

In Python 3.7 or higher I want to test two [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) objects `p1` and `p2` for casefolded equality. Written out I want the result of

```
str(p1).casefold() == str(p2).casefold()
```

Is there a built-in function or operator for this? Or an easier/shorter way to test this?

---

ps: I need this on macOS, but a general solution for `PosixPath` and for `WindowsPath` is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

The only reason you could possibly want to do that is because you are working on Windows which has a case-insensitive filesystem. But `pathlib` knows that.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> uc = Path(r"C:\Program Files")
>>> lc = Path(r"c:\program files")
>>> uc==lc
True
```

Comment: I’m not on Windows. I’m on macOS. I will clarify this in the question.